# Why onmouseover and onclick won't work together setting div styles and how to reset onclick set styles without losing onmouseover's?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, styles, onmouseover

First of all I must say I'm at a very basic programming level. The answer to these questions might be very obvious to some but I just can't think of a way of putting all this together. Thanks in advance.

I've got this HTML code:

```
<div id="vectores" class="categoria" onclick="this.style.color='#000'; this.style.textDecoration='underline'; mostraVectores('vectores0','vectores')" onmouseover="this.style.color='#000'; this.style.textDecoration='underline'" onmouseout="this.style.color='#999'; this.style.textDecoration='none'">Tema 1. Mec&aacute;nica vectorial</div>
    <div id="vectores0" class="subcategoria"></div>
```

I'm using 'onclick' here to make this changes in the styles "permanent", as I want it to be a "menu option" and I want it to trigger the functions but also change it's look so that it can be easily told whether it has been selected or not. I'm using 'onmouseover' to let the user know what the pointer is "about to select" all the time (the menu has more options).

The problem seems to be that they just won't work together. I guess it's just because once the new style has been set by 'onmouseover' the compiler just won't set again the same style for the div if a second event (onclick) asks for it.

Here is the css code for the class:

```
.categoria{
color:#999;
font-weight:bold;
padding:2px;
padding-left:10px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Then I thought to make the change in styles "permanent" using the separate javascript page and the functions like this:

```
function mostraVectores(cosa1,cosa2){

document.getElementById(cosa1).style.display="block";

document.getElementById('equilibrio').style.color="#999";
document.getElementById('estructuras').style.color="#999";
document.getElementById('centros').style.color="#999";
document.getElementById('momento').style.color="#999";
document.getElementById('inercia').style.color="#999";
document.getElementById('rozamiento').style.color="#999";

document.getElementById('equilibrio').style.textDecoration="none";
document.getElementById('estructuras').style.textDecoration="none";
document.getElementById('centros').style.textDecoration="none";
document.getElementById('momento').style.textDecoration="none";
document.getElementById('inercia').style.textDecoration="none";
document.getElementById('rozamiento').style.textDecoration="none";

document.getElementById(cosa2).style.color="#000";
document.getElementById(cosa2).style.textDecoration="underline";

}
```

Here as you can see there are the other "menu options" that I want to turn grey and without the underline (as they are originally according to the css) in case this function is executed after the others', so that the user doesn't end with two "selected-like" menu options when he changes from one topic to the other. The problem is that by "resetting" the styles this way 'onmouseover/onmouseout' in the divs stop working.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try not to use long lines of code in the HTML `onclick`, instead make a function per event.

Comment: Why is that? I mean, even if the syntax is correct? I'm just curious/want to learn.

Comment: By the way, when leaving the styles set to the function in the separate javascript page instead of loading it with onclick I still have the problem with losing onmouseover/onmouseout capabilities as I commented above.

Comment: It's best practice. If you have a single line of code in `onclick` it's no problem, like calling a function, or setting one attribute, but try not to use more than that. It's sloppy and more error-prone.

Comment: Thank you! I'll keep this in mind. Any ideas on how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you need is to use CSS `:hover` and assign a class when clicked.

### HTML

```
<div id="vectores" class="categoria" onclick="mostraVectores('vectores0','vectores')">Tema 1. Mec&aacute;nica vectorial</div>
    <div id="vectores0" class="subcategoria"></div>
```

### CSS

```
.categoria {
    color: #999;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 2px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.categoria:hover { /* This is applied on mouseover and removed on mouseout */
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.categoria.active { /* Not sure what you want when clicked */
    color: #900;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

### JS

```
function mostraVectores(cosa1,cosa2){
    //add this to your function
    this.className += " active";
```

Comment: I didn't know about 'className'! Thank you so much! You helped me a lot! It worked perfectly!